# Recusive Key & Value rename fails in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have two list,
**listA:** (Input)

```
let CAR_DATA= {
  "wheel": {
    "front1": true,
    "front2": true,
    "back1": true,
    "back2": true
  },
  "features": {
    "windshield": true,
    "viper": true,
    "doors": true,
    "horsepower+": true,
    "electric": true
  },
  "example": [
    {
      "general": {
        "name": true,
        "isMMMM": true,
        "isQQQ": false
      },
      "colours_avaliable": {
        "blue": true,
        "black": true,
        "green": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "acknowledgesMistake": false,
        "makes_cheap_cars": true,
        "scandals": true,
      },
      "iid": "0"
    },
      {
      "general": {
        "name": true,
        "isMMMM": false,
        "isQQQ": true
      },
      "colours_avaliable": {
        "blue": true,
        "black": true,
        "green": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "acknowledgesMistake": true,
        "makes_cheap_cars": true,
        "scandals": true,
      },
      "iid": "1"
    }
  ]
};
```

**List B:** (List containing keys to replace list A with)

```
let types: any = {
  "wheel": "Wheel",
  "features": "Features",
  "example": "Example",
  "colours_avaliable": "Colours Avaliable",
  "general": "General",
  "properties": "Properties",
  "front1": "Front Tyre - Left",
  "front2": "Front Tyre - Right",
  "back1": "Back Tyre - Left",
  "back2": "Back Tyre - Right",
  "windshield": "Windshield Present",
  "viper": "Vipers Present",
  "doors": "Doors Present",
  "horsepower+": "Horsepower+ Present",
  "electric": "Electric Present",
  "name": "Quick Registration Name Avaliable",
  "isMMMM": "Belongs to MMM company",
  "isQQQ": "Belongs to QQQ company",
  "blue": "Colour Blue Avaliable",
  "black": "Colour Black Avaliable",
  "green": "Colour Green Avaliable",
  "acknowledgesMistake": "Does it Acknowledge it's mistakes",
  "makes_cheap_cars": "Does it make cheap cars",
  "scandals": "Involved in Scandals",

}
```

What I am trying do is, in ListA, replace 'true' values with Values from List B, delete 'false' values & incase it's a object, just replace key.
Example:

- [True Values] front1: true  ---> front1: Front Tyre - Left
- [False Values] "acknowledgesMistake": false  --->
- {object}  "wheel": {...} ---> "Wheel": {...}

I have come up with the following code:

```
  let CAR_DATA= {
  "wheel": {
    "front1": true,
    "front2": true,
    "back1": true,
    "back2": true
  },
  "features": {
    "windshield": true,
    "viper": true,
    "doors": true,
    "horsepower+": true,
    "electric": true
  },
  "example": [
    {
      "general": {
        "name": true,
        "isMMMM": true,
        "isQQQ": false
      },
      "colours_avaliable": {
        "blue": true,
        "black": true,
        "green": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "acknowledgesMistake": false,
        "makes_cheap_cars": true,
        "scandals": true,
      },
      "iid": "0"
    },
      {
      "general": {
        "name": true,
        "isMMMM": false,
        "isQQQ": true
      },
      "colours_avaliable": {
        "blue": true,
        "black": true,
        "green": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "acknowledgesMistake": true,
        "makes_cheap_cars": true,
        "scandals": true,
      },
      "iid": "1"
    }
  ]
};



let types: any = {
  "wheel": "Wheel",
  "features": "Features",
  "example": "Example",
  "colours_avaliable": "Colours Avaliable",
  "general": "General",
  "properties": "Properties",
  "front1": "Front Tyre - Left",
  "front2": "Front Tyre - Right",
  "back1": "Back Tyre - Left",
  "back2": "Back Tyre - Right",
  "windshield": "Windshield Present",
  "viper": "Vipers Present",
  "doors": "Doors Present",
  "horsepower+": "Horsepower+ Present",
  "electric": "Electric Present",
  "name": "Quick Registration Name Avaliable",
  "isMMMM": "Belongs to MMM company",
  "isQQQ": "Belongs to QQQ company",
  "blue": "Colour Blue Avaliable",
  "black": "Colour Black Avaliable",
  "green": "Colour Green Avaliable",
  "acknowledgesMistake": "Does it Acknowledge it's mistakes",
  "makes_cheap_cars": "Does it make cheap cars",
  "scandals": "Involved in Scandals",

}


//Matches from list1 and replaces true values with list2, deletes false values, calls renameKey() in case of a nested object to rename the key
function replaceValue(item : any, k: string) {

    if(item[k] == true){
      item[k] = types[k];
    }else if(item[k] == false){
      delete item[k];
    }else if(typeof item[k] == "object" && item[k] !== ( null || undefined)){
      item = renameKey(item, k, types[k]);
    }
    return item
}


//Renames the key
const clone = (obj:any) => Object.assign({}, obj);

function renameKey(object:any, key:any, newKey:any){
  debugger
  console.warn(object, key, newKey)
  const clonedObj = clone(object);

  const targetKey = clonedObj[key];



  delete clonedObj[key];

  clonedObj[newKey] = targetKey;

  console.log(clonedObj);

  return clonedObj;
}


// This function handles arrays and objects
function eachRecursive(obj: any)
{
    for (var k in obj)
    {
        if (typeof obj[k] == "object" && obj[k] !== null)
        {
          eachRecursive(obj[k]);
            
        }  
        else
        if(k === 'iid' || !isNaN(Number(k)) ){
          debugger
          continue;
        }
        obj = replaceValue(obj,k);
    }

  return obj;

}

CAR_DATA = eachRecursive(CAR_DATA);

console.log(CAR_DATA);
```

It produces the correct output except for when it goes inside the arrays.

Produced Output (See inside the array, they keys are not changed):

```
    {
        "Wheel": {
            "front1": "Front Tyre - Left",
            "front2": "Front Tyre - Right",
            "back1": "Back Tyre - Left",
            "back2": "Back Tyre - Right"
        },
        "Features": {
            "windshield": "Windshield Present",
            "viper": "Vipers Present",
            "doors": "Doors Present",
            "horsepower+": "Horsepower+ Present",
            "electric": "Electric Present"
        },
        "Example": [
            {
                "general": {
                    "name": "Quick Registration Name Avaliable",
                    "isMMMM": "Belongs to MMM company"
                },
                "colours_avaliable": {
                    "blue": "Colour Blue Avaliable",
                    "black": "Colour Black Avaliable",
                    "green": "Colour Green Avaliable"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "makes_cheap_cars": "Does it make cheap cars",
                    "scandals": "Involved in Scandals"
                },
                "iid": "0"
            },
            {
                "general": {
                    "name": "Quick Registration Name Avaliable",
                    "isQQQ": "Belongs to QQQ company"
                },
                "colours_avaliable": {
                    "blue": "Colour Blue Avaliable",
                    "black": "Colour Black Avaliable",
                    "green": "Colour Green Avaliable"
                },
                "properties": {
                    "acknowledgesMistake": "Does it Acknowledge it's mistakes",
                    "makes_cheap_cars": "Does it make cheap cars",
                    "scandals": "Involved in Scandals"
                },
                "iid": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "Wheel": {
        "front1": "Front Tyre - Left",
        "front2": "Front Tyre - Right",
        "back1": "Back Tyre - Left",
        "back2": "Back Tyre - Right"
    },
    "Features": {
        "windshield": "Windshield Present",
        "viper": "Vipers Present",
        "doors": "Doors Present",
        "horsepower+": "Horsepower+ Present",
        "electric": "Electric Present"
    },
    "Example": [
        {
            "General": {
                "name": "Quick Registration Name Avaliable",
                "isMMMM": "Belongs to MMM company"
            },
            "Colours Avaliable": {
                "blue": "Colour Blue Avaliable",
                "black": "Colour Black Avaliable",
                "green": "Colour Green Avaliable"
            },
            "Properties": {
                "makes_cheap_cars": "Does it make cheap cars",
                "scandals": "Involved in Scandals"
            },
            "iid": "0"
        },
        {
            "General": {
                "name": "Quick Registration Name Avaliable",
                "isQQQ": "Belongs to QQQ company"
            },
            "Colours Avaliable": {
                "blue": "Colour Blue Avaliable",
                "black": "Colour Black Avaliable",
                "green": "Colour Green Avaliable"
            },
            "Properties": {
                "acknowledgesMistake": "Does it Acknowledge it's mistakes",
                "makes_cheap_cars": "Does it make cheap cars",
                "scandals": "Involved in Scandals"
            },
            "iid": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can play around here: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM%20AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL%20gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCoASMFmgY7p7ehCTkVOle4jUMdRLYTqCc8LEZzCZmoNJODPHFZZXVtZYYkAAeRJTInDQS8po%20rf40gnjbDKv8LqD2jpbYoACqAEoAMsK7sUmxkGSCc%20VVQQuaTwVb1UBrDYULY7PagbgUZLJH6QbYmJAECjuMigZEMVDsJzCFLNXxtajBFQ4BoeMheRDwAYMEHsGjfNxmZjsBjMSD8WDQdSJZnwPQiLwAIgAoqsGIgavoJUkcRLwA5UAByYQAOUgEglQRUAHlvmRdoI%20VpIMdUI4FK5pHhQE4GTpRlh9CgEIgYcIruyJIzoiIDBwcd0WGwuNwgsFFCV3DQAMIVJ4AfQAIhUcBUALygADe8dAEr6kBgEvyheLJQlyTY2wAjJW0GR2HyayX6-BtgAmFuoNsdkq16Q9eLNquD9u8TsSseweL9qdD4sAX1ntbxBKJLaLI5Lux49goMG4A6Hm5HErdGwvM7n3HgjME9%20H18wL8gBHgUjIAGo3yvWsYEgWBB3UN91yvCU1jlBUWwAbU7fcDxLXlOB%20BhoD3TsDwlTg5UgIC8OvIQAFlKPIki0LIwQAEVGJbZJsItUiN1IiUEGgMNBDTBgdGwihmXcXDaNHaB2xo8T51qeJpNoiVWHLTgoNojjFIINgNlQU9XyrVDFPHIYJHcbheUEcihFteJiKrFjoAtYC0IlRAZn0NMNA8AhPMcfTWwfcSS0EWAXFYhSRw0lyKAoc8qwlAAGCVOyig9DOvDCsJwgzSNrQjkAi-CKKo5jWPfRShEY%20i1LQ1Lr243j%20MEwURLs6sgtkqSV0CmTpDkwqMuyVTuqUdTnNrLT4B0vSxJk4zfzMiyrMEGy2uncqXLc2y%20K8hgfNC34BtrEKwscga6trGK4pLZsUuLABdRQ1wAbjjRREzQFoCjETgnXzVDS2wCt4rVcscJg7dCUVeKADEPB3RUYLg%20VRPimV4NEmCGsJPiBKE1qWwlJN4B4nHKma4S%20uImDMrIbDCYAcVRLKJRgybpuhktaG0n5dMR4s6wbVBJxLGGheaAZyheSBklQVmBe7PtCbFnsaHwSXQCeChmEwOWYIXCdCYAIXHCWUClmW9YFg3lxLE3FzN%20YtZ1q3ayPbgTzPQnwAyD21DPOgiVRV2S1vH5CYANSoH5hG5z1tnl2snxfQmM2fX5A-jkOJU-X5v1-H5APigAJL8fz-f9M4tBOkfccDKFgQmpTriDYCr4PE5LfK2olej2CFTXIG0Fa6d0ntQG1IjyfxqnO4lYrKONmAe2YYQrCo9F5TMPA58qpj4qN5fOFX8Eqs3ght7nvqupLYnSZxI3JJQCoKYJ-X%20viu%20w1AR-TZfmfMYC2UqiQmX9CSgAZkNaeLVZ4wXmqZSA5l9DLVWqneA%20g0iVEXCZRaKB5BalAIgay7lXwwS2h5Xa%200-JoIwfIQh7kTDYD2uMQ6METo8HCvFAAkpwHQJM9CuAyKAUgp1SHBDXHGEA5F8ReWEN2RAbhrKNh%20q4Jw3QLBryHKAZq7Z3hwkFCtXs-BuCgQUHIsq2jsK6P5NhRyzpUREQANKQDwAACgAJTinGBaJIqRxCYRWogpI0gABWYE2QYCcN3D0oBbJ4EUMkLg4EKDjzUUsCOVjICuPkJABRVZt78HiFWEeoxPFFk7IibJChECIXiPdUAuZ8zrXcelEoOSal1IaZ9Igghan3VegeNcMAfGVPaX0hp%20YHIWhaaRExiY8HVL6QMyKwy8HJFcagFoJIxmdMaSWeAoTwlKgAGTHLSLk8ZABCPZrjBhRGgKAAAPo80A0YZYZEQe4mZtF2ldKiU4lxVTcmFP4JsnpfT3HLJKBIg8TgdxeHaU9SRwAngOOQGve4cTFAIE4CtEwPFMJdNcQckJ%20Rt6eNzAAPlAEaQ54EAgMEEHIZgnBXEFg3MEkJkLgiJPMGPLw-zkDOLcSS8JZLfqFJceKvA-BMISGFdK758IZDsGYLyMgxYcWCBJpAAIuQ6TErpagSVMrBh6mFe4zVPY8UCh7Ig2lISum2swoasJ4FuVWtxWyRwvJUDCqdQS%201oTakuP6W9EoczrRekDdwB1Ia8Bhs1TGuNcrhX1KaT660wrXqeu1e4AIPFmCuOdUGrlOaShwsJF4EtsbQmvQkZSMAOA1ByKSfy0ADgeDuD9GQOmeA-Q8E5eEv4vLknjw8BoVFsAca6CySS-Jv1LXpWSIyUArjBI4kSEIkllq0q5REKkDZWzUgkvGXsiUorwInLOaezp1z8ycHubu8SrS0ITswFOmdehXUQqhUFUA%2061wlH3as-dlTEiNPzBqK6GonkvMuUISe2pXHanYIgaQPxXHxC%20aAJVQUTHSFVeq-dJQcW6UfZAP9gz90kr%20d%20dJmTXW8Gw3%20htFbrRVs5TmhtKZ0xZhzF099n7fiztcbxzM2YKgeq1Tqgt8Ai3if41J56QA) [Tip: Use 'Debugger' & Open Dev Tools to stop the code at any point]

Request 1: Please tell me why my code is not working? I have been spending a lot of time trying to figure it out.

Request 2: As I am newbie, I know my code is very inefficient, please suggest me a beeter approach to this.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to update the input or create a new object?

Comment: @adiga A new object will be better